# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, build, build.gradle

```
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction   
   > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
     Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.
     AAR metadata file: C:\Users\riaju\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a0a024f51da036e6253c9613cd053b1\appcompat-1.4.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

I dont know how to fix this,please help

Tried

```
buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 30
    }
```

Nothing happened

Comment: your problem is not properly defined

Comment: im sorry, i am new to SO, so unable to put the question properly in front of you all

Answer (score 0):

please make the   compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion same

Comment: Tried,nothing happenned

Comment: may i see the fulll build log

Comment: Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-29).
     Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.
     AAR metadata file: C:\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0a0a024f51da036e6253c9613cd053b1\appcompat-1.4.1\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Comment: PLEASE HELP ME IN THIS, THE BUILD IS GETTING FAILED...

Comment: please update your question with, Full gradel file, and log